# What is the meaning of "status code = 7508" on Google Awareness API?

Tags: java, android, kotlin, google-awareness

I implemented Google Awareness API on my application. All the features of Awareness api except getPlace are working. But nearby places features doesn't work. I get the status code 7508. There is no information about that specific code and it's also not handled in the official android documentation.

```
private void getPlace() {
    if (ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(getContext(), android.Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
        return;
    }
    //noinspection MissingPermission
    Awareness.SnapshotApi.getPlaces(mGoogleApiClient)
            .setResultCallback(new ResultCallback<PlacesResult>() {
                @Override
                public void onResult(@NonNull final PlacesResult placesResult) {
                    if (!placesResult.getStatus().isSuccess()) {
                        Toast.makeText(getContext(), "Could not get places.", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                        return;
                    }
                    List<PlaceLikelihood> placeLikelihoodList = placesResult.getPlaceLikelihoods();
            //do smth..
                }
            });
}
```

Comment: [This seems to be a problem not only for you...](https://www.reddit.com/r/mAndroidDev/comments/8la4v8/today_in_googles_world/). I'll cite the link: "Anyway... after a few hours the error resolved itself. So I am guessing it has something to do with the service being down."

Comment: Thank you but I read this document... I've been trying 3 days